# Objective C array not storing value

Tags: objective-c

Forewarning: I'm going through the Itunes Stanford course for IOS, and I'm a complete noob with this language.

I have this function in my "Deck.m" file.

```
- (id)init {
 self = [super init];

 if (self) {
     for (NSString *suit in [Card validSuits]) {
         for (NSUInteger rank = 0; rank < [[Card validRanks] count]; rank++) {
             Card *card = [[Card alloc] init];
             card.contents = [[[Card validRanks] objectAtIndex:rank] stringByAppendingString:suit];
             [self.cards addObject:card];
             NSLog(@"%@", [self.cards count]);
         }
     }
 }

 return self;
}
```

I also have this function in my "Card.h" file (which deck is composed of )

```
@interface Deck : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *cards;

- (Card *)drawRandomCard;

@end
```

The problem I'm having is that when I print the count when running the program, it's always 0. When i try to print the card, they look fine. When I try to print the card by indexing the array, they're all (null).

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.cards` needs to be initialized, otherwise you're calling `-[nil addObject:]`.

Comment: damn it. the exact problem that the professor of the course clearly stated to watch out for. thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you have initialize the array :

inside init initialize it :

```
cards=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```